# Flutter and WordPress Api, not fetching image from website but fetching from assets.image

Tags: flutter, wordpress-rest-api

I am working on an app, i am trying to fetch image from a WordPress API.The image is not fetching, also when using Postman. What could be the issue. The app is fetching blog and all other details.

Comment: If it is not fetching even using Postman means the issue from the api not flutter

Comment: Add your implementation codes.

Answer (score 0):

As @ikerfah has mentioned if you are unable to fetch on Postman, the issue is with the API. However, have a good look at how you have typed in the URL and endpoints associated with the error as this could be causing the issue as well